# How can I program a calculator with a GUI using tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I'm taking computing for GCSE and one of the tasks for our controlled assessment is to create a calculator with a GUI.

I'm able to program a simple calculator without a GUI but I don't understand exactly how it can be done with a GUI.

Below is a code that I got from teampython.wordpress.com, which I vaguely understand but it would be very helpful if someone could explain each individual step to me.

```
 # calc.py - a Python calculator
 from tkinter import *


class Calc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.current = ""
        self.new_num = True
        self.op_pending = False
        self.op = ""
        self.eq = False


    def num_press(self, num):
        self.eq = False
        temp = text_box.get()
        temp2 = str(num)      
        if self.new_num:
            self.current = temp2
            self.new_num = False
        else:
            if temp2 == '.':
                if temp2 in temp:
                    return
            self.current = temp + temp2
        self.display(self.current)

    def calc_total(self):
        self.eq = True
        self.current = float(self.current)
        if self.op_pending == True:
            self.do_sum()
        else:
            self.total = float(text_box.get())

    def display(self, value):
        text_box.delete(0, END)
        text_box.insert(0, value)

    def do_sum(self):
        if self.op == "add":
            self.total += self.current
        if self.op == "minus":
            self.total -= self.current
        if self.op == "times":
            self.total *= self.current
        if self.op == "divide":
            self.total /= self.current
        self.new_num = True
        self.op_pending = False
        self.display(self.total)

    def operation(self, op): 
        self.current = float(self.current)
        if self.op_pending:
            self.do_sum()
        elif not self.eq:
            self.total = self.current
        self.new_num = True
        self.op_pending = True
        self.op = op
        self.eq = False

    def cancel(self):
        self.eq = False
        self.current = "0"
        self.display(0)
        self.new_num = True

    def all_cancel(self):
        self.cancel()
        self.total = 0

    def sign(self):
        self.eq = False
        self.current = -(float(text_box.get()))
        self.display(self.current)

sum1 = Calc()
root = Tk()
calc = Frame(root)
calc.grid()

root.title("Calculator")
text_box = Entry(calc, justify=RIGHT)
text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 5)
text_box.insert(0, "0")

numbers = "789456123"
i = 0
bttn = []
for j in range(1,4):
    for k in range(3):
        bttn.append(Button(calc, text = numbers[i]))
        bttn[i].grid(row = j, column = k, pady = 5)
        bttn[i]["command"] = lambda x = numbers[i]: sum1.num_press(x)
        i += 1

bttn_0 = Button(calc, text = "0")
bttn_0["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(0)
bttn_0.grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = 5)

bttn_div = Button(calc, text = chr(247))
bttn_div["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("divide")
bttn_div.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 5)

bttn_mult = Button(calc, text = "x")
bttn_mult["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("times")
bttn_mult.grid(row = 2, column = 3, pady = 5)

minus = Button(calc, text = "-")
minus["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("minus")
minus.grid(row = 3, column = 3, pady = 5)

point = Button(calc, text = ".")
point["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(".")
point.grid(row = 4, column = 0, pady = 5)

add = Button(calc, text = "+")
add["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("add")
add.grid(row = 4, column = 3, pady = 5)

neg= Button(calc, text = "+/-")
neg["command"] = sum1.sign
neg.grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 5)

clear = Button(calc, text = "C")
clear["command"] = sum1.cancel
clear.grid(row = 5, column = 1, pady = 5)

all_clear = Button(calc, text = "AC")
all_clear["command"] = sum1.all_cancel
all_clear.grid(row = 5, column = 2, pady = 5)

equals = Button(calc, text = "=")
equals["command"] = sum1.calc_total
equals.grid(row = 5, column = 3, pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I'll explain the code you've given as best I understand it. The class `Calc()` contains all the functions for this piece of code. The structure means the main GUI (set up later) can access each function easily. Within the `Calc()` class, you have your functions (denoted by `def` etc.). These contain the various methods by which this code computes it's output.

Outside of the class, we have the Tkinter UI code. This code builds your window inside of which your various buttons and displays sit. The positioning of the buttons and text fields in this case is governed by the 'grid' method. As you can see, every time the code sets up an object (here only `Frame`, `Button` and `Entry` objects), there is an associated `.grid(row=x, column=y...etc)`. This specifies the relative positions of each object in the UI. For example, using the grid method you could stack two objects by giving the first object row=1, column=0 and the second row=2, column=0 etc.

The for loop:

```
for j in range(1,4):
    for k in range(3):
        bttn.append(Button(calc, text = numbers[i]))
        bttn[i].grid(row = j, column = k, pady = 5)
        bttn[i]["command"] = lambda x = numbers[i]: sum1.num_press(x)
        i += 1
```

is probably the only part of the UI that is not straightforward to see if you're just starting out. In essence all it is doing is building buttons automatically (saving you the time to code each one individually). 
The first two lines in the loop are (hopefully) obviously looping over values in specified ranges. Beneath that the line `bttn.append(...` creates a button object in the calc frame set up earlier calc = Frame(root), with the button text being given by the list of numbers (literally `numbers="789456123"` above). Initially, i = 0, so numbers[i] would return the first element in the list numbers, numbers[i] for i=1 (the next time it loops over) would give 8 and so on. The `bttn.grid(row = j, column = k, pady = 5)` uses the grid positioning method mentioned earlier, but here the j and k are given by the values in the loop itself (values between 1 and 4 in the case of rows, and values between 0 and 2 - 3 columns - in the case of columns). If you run the code, you can see that this will position all the keypad buttons for inputting numbers. The last line in this loop (besides i+=1, i.e add 1 to i), handles assigning the button a command. The command will call an associated function, in this case the `numpress` function in `Calc()`. As you may be able to see, `numpress` itself updates your display with whatever number you press.

The final block of code in this example handles the remaining operations for the calculator, and you will notice that each also follows the above pattern of creating a button, assigning a command and positioning the button in the UI. With what I've explained above, you may be able to see that each of the remaining functions in `Calc()` governs an arithmetical operation, or clear etc.

I realise this is a wall of text, but I hope it helps! If I've been unclear or there is anything in particular you don't understand, let me know, I'll try and explain it (I've not long learnt myself!).

You might find this [Tkinter UI Guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm) useful, I learnt a lot of the basics from that guide.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a GUI library in Python like [PyQt4](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/), [wxPython](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/) or [Tkinter](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/). The question is too broad to give you anymore details.

Start with the tutorials that teach you all the basics you need to know about creating GUIs in Python.

PS: Personally, I would suggest you to go with `PyQt`.

Comment: Why go with PyQt? For a beginner who is learning GUI programming, what is wrong with tkinter? It is a *fantastic* GUI toolkit for learning, plus it is probably already installed. I have nothing against PyQt, but if you're going to give advice, at least explain _why_ you suggest going with something different. Without an explanation, the advice is useless.